# insert and retrieve image from Blob

Tags: php, mysql, image, blob

I'm doing something wrong while inserting or retrieving a image in/from a mysql blob field.
I looked at a lot of questions allready asked here at stackoverflow, but cant get mine to work.

field:

```
<input type="file" name="filename" id="filename" />
```

inserting code:

```
$img = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents(
    $_FILES['filename']['tmp_name']
)));
$insrtSQL = "
    INSERT INTO table (s_id, s_name, s_image, s_text, s_link, t_id) 
    VALUES ('a', 'a', '$img', 'a', 'a', 'a')
";
```

echoing code

```
<?php 
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . 
     base64_encode($row_Sss['s_image']) . 
     '" width="290" height="290">' 
?>
```

I know i should use MySQLi or PDO instead, but thats not an option for now.
What am I missing? or doing wrong?

Comment: Is exposing your data to anyone who's interested an 'option'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wait... Are you BASE64 encoding your data - twice?

First you do a *base64_encode()* on the uploaded file, then you select it from your table later on and *echo()* it yet again with *base64_encode()*. Try removing the base64_encode when doing your echo, and also try omitting the chunk_split() command when inserting data into the table.

Also, you don't have to base64 encode any data if you're looking to store binary data into a mySQL blob field, just do something this:

```
$img = mysql_real_escape_string(file_get_contents($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name']));
```

Then you may echo it with base64_encode() in your HTML.

Remember, since you're storing large chunks of data in your table, avoid using "SELECT ***** " queries, as this will significantly decrease performance. If you'll be storing much more larger chunks of data in your database, consider moving your data to the disk.

Comment: TNX. it worked! Tnx for the help!! I'm a very happy person right now

Answer (score 2):

Your insert statement is just inserting a base64 string, not the base64-encoded data.  Try passing it through the [MySQL FROM_BASE64 function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_from-base64):

```
$insrtSQL = "INSERT INTO table (s_id, s_name, s_image, s_text, s_link, t_id) VALUES ('a', 'a', FROM_BASE64('$img'), 'a', 'a', 'a')";
```

This makes the MySQL engine decode the base64 string back into binary data for storage.

Comment: hmmm the server version is still on mysql version 5.5.32 so this function is not avaliable :(

Comment: In that case, you could just store the data as a base-64 encoded string, instead of a blob, and echo it straight out as-is in the `<img>` tag?

Comment: Tnx daiscog, I applied Normal's overrated sollution and this worked.